# Make a FB Like make new content appear for user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I use this code to generate the Facebook like button on my website:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/URL-TO-FBPAGE"  width="30" action="like" layout="button_count" id="f1"></fb:like>
```

It works fine. Now what I want to do is that I want the user to see a hidden content after clicking the like button. For instance a "welcome to community" image. How is this possible? I have seen other generating a code that does this but I never saved the source code.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the edge.create JavaScript  event and then show it there.  You won't be able to tell I they previously liked it though without prompting them for permissions to your profile.